# Good place for complex methods that answer a question

Tags: domain-driven-design

Here is some example code in which we have a method that answers the questions "Can User X review Product Y?"

```
public namespace Domain
{
    public class User
    {
        ...

        public bool CanWriteReview(Product product)
        {
             return this.IsApproved
                 && !Kernel.Get<ReviewRepository>().UserHasReviewed(product)
                 && !Kernel.Get<SellerAccountRepository>().UserHasSellerAccount(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like having this method in a Domain POCO because it has too many dependencies that can't be injected and must be retrieved directly from the kernel instead. Where would you put this type of logic?

I find that the [domain events pattern](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/) is a useful means of taking service-like logic that depends on Domain state changes, out of the Domain. Is there a similar pattern for the sort of methods above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Specification Pattern](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/03/02/ddd-the-specification-pattern.aspx) is a good candidate for this kind of thing.